# How to convert the UTC time into the device time in android when using GPS?

Tags: android, gps, utc

Hi All please any one can tell how to convert the UTC time into the android device current time....

Actually when we are using the GPS service in mobile I am displaying lat,lon,altitude and  time

Here the time is coming in format of UTC milliseconds I want to convert that time into the device current time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
d.toLocaleString(); //to phone's locale
d.toGMTString(); //in GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
String dat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy").format(location.getTime())
```